# Java regex for preceding character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to construct a regex to check if a letter occurs in a string, it should be **precede** only one of 2 other characters. I can do this for one set of chars, but how do I do it for multiple sets in a string?

For example: C can only precede A or B, i.e. if C is found the next char can only be A or B. F can only precede D or E (F cannot precede A or B)

A or B, then C can occur
D or E, then F can occur

How do I do this?

The following gives me an error:

```
String pattern = "([F][D|E])|([A][B|C])";
String test = "FEAC";
System.out.println(test.matches(pattern));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the only allowable letters are A to F, you can use this:

```
^(?:C[AB]|F[DE]|[ABDEG-Z])+$
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/55)

**Explanation**

- The anchors won't be necessary with the `matches` method, but explaining them for the raw version:
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string
- Match `C[AB]` a C then an A or B, OR `|`
- `F[DE]` an F then a D or E, OR `|`
- `[ABDEG-Z]` one of these letters
- `+` one or more times

**Option: Allowing C and F at the end of the string**

If you want to allow C or F at the end of the string, add this: `|[CF]$` (one of several ways to do it)

The regex becomes:

```
^(?:C[AB]|F[DE]|[ABDEG-Z]|[CF]$)+$
```

In Java:

```
if (subjectString.matches("(?:C[AB]|F[DE]|[ABDEG-Z])+")) {
    // It matched!
  } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  
     }
```

Comment: FYI added a second option in case you also want to allow F or C at the end of the string (no following letters)

Comment: can we make it generic for all other alphabets as well?

Comment: yes, this works. following on from Braj, how can I allow other characters to exist as well? For example CBYIU should give true

Comment: @Braj Made minor tweak to allow other characters. stretchr, please see revised answer. :)

Comment: thanks :) tried this: "(?:I[XV]|X[LC]|[XVLC-Z])+" but it doesn't work with "IVXCIXXLA". It works if I replace A with Z or X or something. How can I make it work for A as well?

Comment: `IVXCIXXLA` cannot match with my regex, because C is followed by I. Or is this a new question? If so, and if the first answer worked, please consider accepting and / or upvoting. Thanks! Starting a movie now, will check in later. :)

Comment: yup, your answer is good. But I have a follow-up, asked the qn in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736720/regex-precedence-for-multiple-characters

Comment: Thanks, glad this one helped. :)

Comment: Will have a look at the other one. :)

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava! Off to sleep, see you tomorrow. :)