# Regex multiple repeating characters with one interjection in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regex to check if a character repeats 5 consecutive times. If the character repeats 6 times, an allowable character between the fifth and seventh character must be present. I can do this for one character, but am unable to concatenate the check for multiple characters. How should I concatenate?

Explanation of above:

YYYYY -> 5 consecutive times, so this is true

YYYYYHY -> 6 repeats with allowable character between 5th and 6th repeat, also true

My current regex:

```
"(.*Y{4}(([LCDH]Y)|Y).*)"  // this works fine in meeting the requirement above

"(.*Y{4}(([LCDH]Y)|Y).*)|(.*T{4}(([DM]T)|T).*)" // this does not work fine
```

For the second expression, a case of YYYYYYTTTTTQT, gives me false (because TTTTTQT is wrong) but I want it to give me true because YYYYY is correct.

TTTTTQT is wrong because between the fifth and sixth T, only D or M can exist. So while TTTTT would be correct, the existence of Q after that and before the sixth T makes it wrong. Alternatively, TTTTTDT or TTTTTMT would be correct.

**How do I ensure that if concatenating multiple such conditions, I get a True if one of them is true?**

Comment: If you're checking at first if it repeats 5 times then why not use `Y{5}` instead of `{4}` ?

Comment: Please make your requirements more clear, it is ununderstandable. Why `TTTTTQT` is wrong?

Comment: try it, if you do that, you'll get a false for YYYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^(?:Y{5}(?![^HY]Y)|T{5}(?![^DMT]T))[A-Z]*
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?:` start non-capture group which contains an `|` alternation
- `Y{5}` match 5 Ys
- `(?![^HY]Y)` asserts that this is not followed by one char that is neither H nor Y then a Y
- `|` or
- `T{5}` match 5 Ts
- `(?![^DMT]T)` asserts that this is not followed by one char that is neither D nor M nor T then a T
- `)` end non-capture group
- `[A-Z]*` match any trailing chars

Comment: Tweaked and added explanation, let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: cool, I'm getting this. But YYYYYAA returns false. How to modify this to accept other characters?

Comment: Please see the updated answer, let me know if that's closer. :)

Comment: almost there, except we need to have the [A-Z]* at the start of the string too as the occurrence of the characters can happen anywhere. 
^[A-Z]*(?:Y{5}(?![^HY]Y)|T{5}(?![^DMT]T))[A-Z]*

Answer (score 1):

Okay first of all you're using regex so you don't need to tack .* to each side...

So this:

```
(.*Y{4}(([LCDH]Y)|Y).*)|(.*T{4}(([DM]T)|T).*)
```

becomes:

```
(Y{4}(([LCDH]Y)|Y))|(T{4}(([DM]T)|T))
```

Second of all this should work fine for finding 'YYYYY' in anything... although you can shorten and make it more readable by reducing it to:

```
Y{4}[LCDH]?Y|T{4}[DM]?T
```

Either of those or'ed expressions should match on 'YYYYYTTTTTQT' so I can only assume you're not using the regex correctly?

Comment: exactly numeral. thanks for simplifying. But I get a false even though YYYYY is in YYYYYTTTTTQT. I'm trying to find out how to get true

Comment: and I'm not so sure we should remove the .*condition.*, it's meant to say whatever characters before/after it don't matter. When I did remove it, I got a false returned for YYYYY. So I think it shld be kept.

Comment: That might be a java implementation issue (the .* thing). I've tried this using python's re module and works perfectly fine for me so I can only assume it's a java issue and I'm not really familiar with java regex issues. Sorry. :(

Comment: no worries, got me to think about the need for .* and be clearer in understanding regex